# Problem when loading multiple files in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have several parquet files that I want to process with Spark. I tried

```py
df = spark.read
            .parquet('*.parquet')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
```

but when I run an sql query such as:

```sql
SELECT col1, LAST(col1) FROM df
```

it seems to only look  at the last element **within the same file**. Is this an expected behavior, and if so, is there any way to overcome that?

What I do at the moment is:

```py
fnames = !ls *.parquet
df = None
for fname in fnames:
    if df is None: 
        df = spark.read.parquet(fname)
    else: 
        df = df.union(spark.read.parquet(fname))
```

which works as expected but it is really slow.

Answer (score 1):

Create sql context:

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local', "retail")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Read using sql context:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(path/to/folder)
```

Above code reads all parquet files in the `folder` specified by the path.